# Потеря части содержимого параметра url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Работаю с `summernote` редактором при вставке с какого текста с сайта в него ,его  оформление сохраняется.

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 200,
        onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
          sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
        }
    });
```

Затем я получаю  `html` разметку внутри блока-редактора,передаю его параметром в обработчик

```
 textcode = $('#summernote').code();

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addcode.php",
               data: "title="+titlearticle+"&code=" + textcode + "&preview_img="+preview_img+"&language="+language,
                success: function(result) {
                  alert("Добавлено"+result);

                  $('#summernote').code('');
                }
              });
            })
```

и записываю

```
include './config.php';


$title=$_POST['title'];

$code=$_POST['code'];


$preview_img_not_clear=$_POST['preview_img'];
$preview_img=str_replace("../../imgnews/","",$preview_img_not_clear);


$data=date("Y-m-d");
$language=$_POST['language'];



$data = array( 'title' => "$title", 'code' => "$code", 'preview_img' => "$preview_img", 'data' => "$data", 'language' => "$language" );  
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO news (title, code, preview_img,data,language) values (:title, :code, :preview_img,:data,:language)");  
$STH->execute($data);
echo $code;
```

Проблема в том,что если взять и просто написать текст ,то он сохраниться без проблем,если же вставить текст с разметкой, он в самом редакторе отобразит нормально

```
textcode = $('#summernote').code();
```

в этой части тоже выведет нормально,но в базу уже запишет не полностью,а только кусок,причем как то странной обрезает,каждую разметку по разному.

**UPD**
Часть проблемы обнаружено,он переставал записывать когда натыкался на `&nbsp`

Comment: Сделайте encodeURIComponent для пересылаемого текста

Answer (score 1):

Ну так замените &nbsp за пробел через str_replace, и все

Comment: Это я уже сделал,но все равно ,на некоторые символы реагирует так же,хоть я и пробовал  `htmlspecialchars`  и `mysql_real_escape_string `